# How to save fuzzy search index between sessions?

Tags: editor, atom-editor, fuzzy-search

I normally start my working sessions by moving to the root of my code tree and issuing `atom .`.

However I work with moderately big trees (in excess of 100.000 files) and I noticed that atom needs to re-index the entire project at each launch.

**Is there a way to tell Atom to save the index for the following session [and eventually to reindex based on a diff] ?**

Comment: It looks like there's a github issue open for this problem: https://github.com/atom/fuzzy-finder/issues/88